# Client side encryption - best practice

Tags: encryption, cryptography, password-protection

I wrote a "Password Locker" C# app a while ago as an exercise in encryption. I'd like to move the data to the web so that I can access it anywhere without compromising my password data. I'd just like to run my ideas by the community to ensure I'm not making a mistake as I'm not an encryption expert.

Here's what I envision:

1. In the C# app all the password data is encrypted as a single chunk of text using a user supplied password.  I'm using Rijndael (symmetric encryption) in CBC mode.  The password is salted using a hard coded value.
2. Encrypted data gets sent to my database
3. I go to a web page on my server and download the encrypted text.  Using client side javascript I input my password.  The javascript will decrypt everything (still client side)

Here are my assumptions:

- I assume that all transmissions can be intercepted
- I assume that the javascript (which contains the decryption algo, and hard coded salt) can be intercepted (since it's really just on the web)
- The password **cannot** be intercepted (since it's only input client side)
- The result is that someone snooping could have everything except the password.

So, based on those assumptions: Is my data safe? I realize that my data is only as safe as the strength of my password... Is there something I can do to improve that? Is Rijndael decryption slow enough to prevent brute force attacks?

I thought about using a random salt value, but that would still need to be transmitted and because of that, it doesn't seem like it would be any safer. My preference is to not store the password in any form (hashed or otherwise) on the web.

**Edit:**
I am considering using SSL, so my "interception" assumptions may not be valid in that case.

**Edit 2:**
Based on comments from Joachim Isaksson, I will be running with SSL.  Please continue breaking apart my assumptions!

**Edit 3:**
Based on comments from Nemo I will use salt on a per user basis.  Also, I'm using PBKDF2 to derive a key based on passwords, so this is where I'll get my "slowness" to resist brute force attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without even going into the crypto analysis in any way, if you're assuming all your information can be intercepted (ie you're running without SSL), you're **not** secure.

Since anyone can intercept the Javascript, they can also *change* the Javascript to make the browser pass the clear text elsewhere once decrypted.

Also, anyone hacking into the site (or the site owner) can maliciously change the Javascript to do the same thing even if SSL is on.

Comment: Can js be modified en route if I'm running without SSL?  I only assume that the js can be intercepted because someone snooping could see the web address of the js and go view it for themselves.

Comment: @MikeH Yes, anything passed from or to the server can be changed en route if you're running without SSL. Always count on your users to use the unencrypted WiFi at Starbucks :)

Answer (score 2):

By "password data", I assume you mean "password-protected data"?

The salt does need to be random.  It is fine that is transmitted in the clear.  The purpose of a salt is protection against dictionary attacks.  That is, should someone manage to obtain your entire encrypted database, they could quickly try a large dictionary of passwords against *all* of your users.  With random salts, they need to try the dictionary against *each* user.

Or, alternatively, even without compromising the database, they could generate a huge collection of pre-encrypted data for lots of dictionary words, and immediately be able to recognize any known plaintext encrypted by any of those keys.

Even with a salt, dictionary attacks can be faster than you would like, so deriving key data from a password is a lot more subtle than most people realize.

Bottom line:  As always, never invent your own cryptography, not even your own modes of operation.  To derive an encryption key from a password, use a well-known standard like [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) (aka. PKCS#5).

Comment: I'm sold on a per user salt.  I'd forgotten that I'm using Rfc2898DeriveBytes to derive keys (which follows the PBKDF2 standard). I guess this is the "slowness" I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, by "password data" I mean "password-protected data"...well both since it's a password locker :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as this is an open question:

---

Issue #1

What are you going to do if the password that is supplied is incorrect, or if the salt/ciphertext is altered? You will get an incorrect decryption result, but how are you going to test that? What happens if just the last part of the ciphertext is altered? Or removed altogether?

Solution: Provide integrity protection against such attacks. Add a HMAC using a different key or use a mode like GCM mode.

---

Issue #2

What happens if you change or add a few bytes to the password (compare the encrypted store in time)?

Solution: Encrypt your key store with a different IV each time.

---

That's already 4 issues found :) Cryptography is hard.

Comment: Yes, it is hard, it also makes it fun!  I've just been reading up on HMAC, so it's something I'll need to consider.  I hadn't heard of GCM mode, but a quick search makes it seem promising.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean in Issue #2, could you elaborate?

Comment: Say you have a password of 10 characters, and they are on a block boundary. If you change the last characters, only the blocks that contain these characters and subsequent blocks are changed. This leaks information, e.g. an attacker could assume that you only did a tiny edit on your password, after you thought it was compromised. It's not much of a leak, but it certainly *is* a leak. Many devs forget to take time/versions of files in account regarding crypto.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating.  I assume using a using a key derivation function (such as PBKDF2) takes care of this kind of attack right?  Also, completely unrelated to this comment (and probably the wrong place for this question): I feel like all the answers here provide good information.  Can I mark all of them as answers or do I pick one (or none)?

Comment: To be honest, your question is not entirely fit for stackoverflow for this reason ("...but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion"). But you can vote up the answers and then pick the one that helped you most I suppose. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers

Comment: PBKDF2 is normally used to calculate the IV too. This is not a problem if you pick a new random salt each time, as this will generate a new key and IV. Otherwise the key and IV are likely static, and this will lead to vulnerabilities like I described when you use CBC encoding, *and it will reveal plain text when used with CTR or GCM mode encoding*.